# In Flux architecture, how do you manage analytics tracking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, analytics, reactjs-flux

Let's say I'm building a single page application like Airbnb. One thing that would be good in such application is to track when someone creates an account.

For the tracking part, there are a lot of services that would help (google analytics, segment, etc).

For example, to track an event using [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) you simply can use the following:

```
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'User',
  action: 'Created an Account'
});
```

But my question is... how this should be done in a flux architecture?

Should I dispatch an action and add a middleware for this action? Or just call that function directly inside of `signUp` action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few times I had to code very similar thing for services like [Intercom](https://www.intercom.com/). I used Redux at that time. In event-driven architecture, which Redux based apps are, you can do it in a very attractive way just by using middlewares.

In my case, I have noticed that I already have all required actions and all I need is just send a request to an analytics too after some action was triggered.

Something like this:

```
function sendIntercomRequest(action) {
  // send a request to analytic tool here
}

const intercomMiddreware = store => next => action => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // take required events
    case actionTypes.SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
    case actionTypes.SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS:
      sendIntercomRequest(action.type);
      break;
  }

  return next(action);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I might think of action "signUp" which ist being dispatched to an "singUpReducer". Just like:

```
export function signUp(username){
    return {
            type: SIGNUP,
            username: username
    };
}
```

And the reducer might be look like:

```
export default function signUpReducer(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type){
    case SIGNUP:
        return action.username;
    default:
       return state;
   }
}
```

Of course you trigger the action in your specifc component or map it from a "container" via mapDispatchToProps to a "presentational" component. 
I dont see here any point to use a middleware except you want to transform your dispatched actions payload anyhow. 
I hope it helped you, even when I tried to explain it in a "Redux-way".